# pgcli not working in windows 11. How to install it properly?

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgcli

**Problem** -

I used `pip install pgcli` on my command prompt. And then used `pgcli --version` It is giving me this error -

```
C:\Users\Adarsh>pgcli --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Scripts\pgcli.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pgcli\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pgspecial.namedqueries import NamedQueries
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pgspecial\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import dbcommands
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pgspecial\dbcommands.py", line 7, in <module>
    from psycopg.sql import SQL
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\psycopg\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import pq  # noqa: F401 import early to stabilize side effects
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\psycopg\pq\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    import_from_libpq()
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\psycopg\pq\__init__.py", line 106, in import_from_libpq
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: no pq wrapper available.
Attempts made:
- couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
- couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
- couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
```

**What I tried** -

- I tried `pip install psycopg2`, still same error after using `pgcli --version`
- I also tried doing everything in the new environment `conda create --name pgcli_env python=3.8` but still same error.

**My pc** -

- Windows 11
- Python 3.11.4
- PostgreSQL 16 App Installed

**Question** -

- How to use `pgcli` on windows?

Comment: Pip installs libraries for python to use in a python script

Comment: Also reading the webpage, that is not for windows

Comment: Have you installed python-dev, libpq-dev and libevent-dev packages before installing pgcli?

Comment: @nbk I am following a this [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/2JM-ziJt0WI?list=PL3MmuxUbc_hJed7dXYoJw8DoCuVHhGEQb&t=424) and the instructor is using pgcli on windows.

Comment: @cmucheru I am not able to install these packages using `pip install`. It is giving me error `ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-dev`

Comment: They have under two https://www.pgcli.com/faq some hints

Comment: These packages are mostly for Linux distro, not from Python, therefore pip will not work. Installing on Windows might be a longer process as you might need to build the packages from source.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Find the path where postgresql is installed on pc. So something like C:\ postgresql\15\bin. Locate the bin folder then copy the path and add it into system environment variable - add it in path (system env variable). After the sys env variable is added i uninstalled pgcli - pip uninstall pgcli and then opened a new terminal and reinstalled it. Works fine

Answer (score 0):

Install this and it'll work fine

```
pip install psycopg_binary
```

I recently faced the same issue and this fixed the issue immediately.

See [here](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg-binary/) for a description of the package.